# Why is my (thunderbolt connected) monitor not detected in Fedora 23

Tags: linux, fedora, configuration, monitors

I have a Dell XPS13 whose Philips UltraWide monitor connected is via a Thunderbolt 3/USB-C connection.  As no monitor other than Apple monitors support this new fangled connection, I have an external converter to HDMI (I've also tried to DVI and Mini HDMI).
My monitor is not detected by Fedora 23 however.  There's nothing useful in */etc/X11/xorg.conf.d*, only a keyboard conf.  Also nothing useful in */usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d*.

I've tried restarting, restarting with it plugged in, not plugged in, restarting in terminal mode (plugged in and not) and running `startx`

Any ideas why or is there anything I can try?  There is always the possibility of course that it's not supported.  The Wifi on this thing isn't supported by Linux yet.

**Linux Kernel 4.1 & 4.2 Bug**

There is an existing [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1260796) with Thunderbolt on Linux Kernel 4.1, 4.2 and 4.3 but I've downloaded Fedora 22 Live and booted from that (which uses Kernel 4.0) and I have the same problem.

**xrandr -q**

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

**lspci -v**

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0704
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at db000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: i915
```

and my kernel is up to date

**uname -a**

```
Linux localhost.localdomain 4.2.6-300.fc23.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 10 19:32:21 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**find /dev -group video**

```
/dev/video0
/dev/fb0
```

**glxinfo | grep -i vendor**

```
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
```

**cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep "(EE)"**

```
[  1838.502] (EE) 
[  1838.503] (EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE) 
[  1838.503] (EE) 
[  1838.503] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[  1838.503] (EE) 
[  1838.503] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

**Xorg.0.log** - Other parts that may be relevant

```
[    11.762] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    11.762] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    11.762] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    11.762] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    11.763] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
...
[    11.772] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[    11.772] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[    11.772] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[    11.772] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[    11.772] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    11.772] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    11.772] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    11.772] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    11.772]    compiled for 1.17.99.901, module version = 2.99.917
[    11.772]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    11.772]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    11.772] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    11.772] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    11.773] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    11.773]    compiled for 1.18.0, module version = 1.18.0
[    11.773]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    11.773]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    11.773] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    11.773] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    11.773] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    11.773]    compiled for 1.17.99.901, module version = 0.4.3
[    11.773]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    11.773]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    11.773] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    11.773] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    11.773] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    11.773]    compiled for 1.17.99.901, module version = 2.3.2
[    11.773]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    11.773]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    11.773] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[    11.773] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics: 2000-6000
[    11.773] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics: 5100, 6100
[    11.773] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics: 5200, 6200, P6300
[    11.773] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1260796) where Thunderbolt connections aren't recognized in Linux kernel 4.1, 4.2 and 4.3 but are in 4.0.

This has been fixed in kernel 4.4 so adding an updated kernel fixes it.  As Fedora 23 didn't update to 4.4. till Fedora 24 (Actually 4.6).  If you are using an older version, it can be [done manually](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Kernel_Vanilla_Repositories) as follows

**Add the Kernel Vanilla Repo**

```
curl -s https://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/thl/kernel-vanilla.repo | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/kernel-vanilla.repo
```

**Install the stable release (or dev [*kernel-vanilla-mainline*] if you're brave)**

```
sudo dnf --enablerepo=kernel-vanilla-stable update
```

Then restart, kernel 4.4 will be an option on startup.

I've no idea why Fedora with Kernel 4.0 didn't work though.